# Angular search filter

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I'm trying to implement search filter in angular 2 for that I Have implement below code

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import{Pipe,PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], criteria: any): any {

        return items.filter(item =>{
           for (let key in item ) {
             if((""+item[key]).toLocaleLowerCase().includes(criteria.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                return true;
             }
           }
           return false;
        });
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements P {
  title = 'app';
    users:any[]=[
           {sid:124,sname:"Angular"},
           {sid:125,sname:"Ionic"},
           {sid:126,sname:"mobile"}]
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h4>Creating Custom Pipes</h4>
 <input #search  (keyup)="0">
 <div *ngFor="let user of (users | searchFilter: search.value )">
   {{user.sname}}
  </div>  
</div>
```

But in the browser console log it is showing below error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:The pipe 'searchFilter' could not be found (".

I'm not able to figured out what is the error. Could any one please help to achieve this

Comment: You need to add `SearchFilter` to your module declarations

Comment: And just for next time: if you create your pipe with `ng generate pipe SearchFilter`, angular-cli will create the files and inject the correct modules into your app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Add **`SearchFilter`** in your module under declarations

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,  
    SearchFilter  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```